# DNS lookup in internal network

Tags: dns, website, windows-server-2012

I am having trouble with figuring out how to change the lookup of my internal website. As I am a software developer not a network specialist so I can't seem to figure out how to go about this or where to start.

So here is my issue. I have an internal website and I have it setup on my serer using IIS 8.0. To access this website using a client computer I need to type the server's IP address into the browser address bar.

What I am looking to do is change the DNS lookup (I think it is a DNS lookup) so I can type in a name for the site (eg. "operations"). When the user types in operations into the browser it will navigate to my website. Any help is appreciated.

I am using Windows Server 2012, Windows 7 64-bit, and Google Chrome.

Comment: Could this help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779029%28v=ws.10%29.aspx ..

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you need to have a DNS server, and the DHCP server should give your server IP address as DNS server.

The DNS server itself then has to provide the domain to IP translation, and everything else it should get from the internet. If you use a router with DHCP, it is likely to also use the ISP's DNS server, and thus your clients will never get your domain to ip translation done correctly.

Comment: From my understanding we have a DNS server at our office

Comment: Then configure your domain entry in that DNS server and make it point to your server's ip.

Comment: This is what I need help with. I don't know much about network. I do not know how to make the DNS server point to the server's IP.

Comment: Go to administrative tools->DNS server. From there simply add the domain and ip. It is pretty straight forward, really.

Comment: Either deploy a hosts file edit to redirect the domain of your choice to the IP address using a GPO, or simply add a new DNS record on the server.. It's really, really simple. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYj7KSIn2Xo

Comment: @SamuelNicholson I recommend against using GPO with hosts file. You only want to be using a hostfile to deny access, not grant access. If for some reason a pc is not part of the network anymore, that hosts file will still be there, and no one will ever find it again, because its not common practice. A DNS Server really is the way to go, and its simple as your video shows.

Comment: @LPChip I completely agree, plus if OP can't add a DNS entry I don't think his knowledge of the hosts file or GPO's for that matter will be exemplary.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to reply for a while. So this is a forward, or a reverse lookup?

Comment: A forward lookup. You cannot even do a reverse lookup. A reverse lookup is only something your ISP can set for you, but you don't need that anyway.